# How to do force backup bios on gigabyte z390 aorus ultra motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, bios

i enabled a setting in the bios recently(see my previous post) due to which my pc is not booting and doing a cmos reset didnt work, so my only choice now is the backup bios, but the usual method of holding the power button till it starts and shuts down doesnt bring up the backup bios,i wld also like to mention that my mobo is still alive due to the led error codes are working and soare my other rgb leds

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, that Z390 board has a mechanical switch for the backup BIOS function.  Do note that there are issues with dual BIOS mode, so you'll want to do more research on how to properly utilize this feature.

I've located the diagrams that show where the switches are located:

[image][image]

Comment: That's not my motherboard unfortunately, that's aorus master, mine's aorus ultra

Comment: Wow, that is *incredibly* misleading, but thanks for pointing that out.  I tried searching in more detail but had trouble parsing through the unrelated hits.  I would suggest that you directly ask on their [Discord](http://redirect.viglink.com/?key=71fe2139a887ad501313cd8cce3053c5&subId=6560288&u=https%3A//discord.gg/59ZMN6J) server instead, hopefully you'll have better luck there.